# Angular 2+: Changing variables within template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How would you change an existing Typescript variable from the template?

**Example**

```
<a class="header">{{myVar}}</a>

<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="{{ submission.FileName }}" *ngFor="let submission of submissions | async">

        <input myVar="submission.FileName" /> <-- SET VARIABLE HERE -->

    </mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to hoist out the variable information in the current tab to the header above.

Comment: where have you defined 'myVar' and 'submissions'. Can you show some more codes of '.ts' and 'html template'.

Comment: `myVar;` and in ngOnInit() I have: 
`this.submissionsCollection = this.afs.collection(pathSubmissions);
    this.submissions = this.submissionsCollection.valueChanges();`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution

Use an `iframe` and the `load` event to pass the current `UserName` to a function which sets `myVar`. It worked but it also gave me a *change error*, for which I need to import and use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

**Template**

```
<a class="header">{{myVar}}</a>

<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="{{ submission.FileName }}" *ngFor="let submission of submissions | async">
        <iframe (load)="message(submission.UserName)" style="width:0px; height:0px;"></iframe>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

myVar;

message(userName) {
    this.myVar= userName;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input [myVar]='submission.FileName' />`

in your component.ts

`import { Input } from '@angular/core';`

`@Input() myVar: any;`

FONT: [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs)

Comment: It's giving me an error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'myVar' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("e" [value]="submission.FileName">`

Comment: I get the same - Angular2 can be a struggle sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a class="header">{{myVar}}</a>
<mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab label="{{ submission.FileName }}" *ngFor="let submission of submissions | async">
  <input [(ngModel)]="submission.FileName" (change)="myVar = submission.FileName"/> <-- SET VARIABLE HERE -->
 </mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: This populates the input with the FileName. I want to take the value of the current FileName and spit it out up top into the header. Is there no way of simply changing a Typescript value from the template?

Comment: i think i am not getting your point, it is possible to change the typescript value from template thats why there is two way binding.

Comment: I'm trying to find the same thing @FiringBlanks and its been driving me demented for the entire day.....all I want to do is change a variable in the component from within the template. I'm beginning to think it can't be done....